# Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial: User.find(1) after destroy method shows stack trace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org, rails-console

I'm going through Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial, specifically Chapter 6:

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-one#sec:finding_user_objects

after I do the User.find(1) after user.destroy command, I get the below error message:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :006 > User.find(1)
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with ID=1
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:304:in `find_one'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:289:in `find_with_ids'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:107:in `find'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:444:in `find'
    from (irb):6
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I'm new to programming in general, and I'm not sure where to proceed. Googling the error messages didn't turn up anything useful. Everything looks fine, I just don't know why I got the error message in additional with the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're new to programming one key thing is to take a close look at the error message.

Unfortunately, sometimes the error messages are a little cryptic and personally I find that I often have to read them twice, especially if it's a new programming language you are trying to learn.

Now to deconstruct the sequence of the errors.

In this case the error shows that you don't have a record, as per the message:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with ID=1
```

The error resulted because you were trying to find a user with ID of 1.  The original operation was:

```
User.find(1)
```

Which, as per your comment was proceeded by a 'Destroy' operation, thus removing the data.  That of course assumes that you had either one record, or requested this one record to be destroyed.  Of course, as others have stated, the **find** operation throws an exception

The API is documented at [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) and what you want is details on find method which describes:

If no record can be found for all of the listed ids, then RecordNotFound will be raised.

Another good reference is [API Dock](http://apidock.com)

Answer (score 1):

You will not get exception if you do

```
 User.first(:conditions => { :id => 1 })
```

The reason why you get exception is that Rails assume that if you use find(id) method you expect that such object exists. If there is no object with given id, it treats it as an error and exception is raised. On the other hand If you use .first method and you write condition, you do not tell rails that you expect this object to exists - it might but might not, that is why in that case no exception is raised.
It is a little bit tricky :) hope it is a little bit clear, why you get exception in your case and not with the one I have written. It is simple matter of interpretation of your expectation.

Comment: Ah ok, so I'm assuming the stack trace is "intended behavior?"

Comment: Or `find_by_id`, which is a shorter version of the above.

Answer (score 0):

`find` results in an error being raised upon failure, whereas `find_by_<attribute here>` methods just return `nil`.  So in this case you can use `find_by_id` which will return nil instead of a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You can also catch the exception, and take other actions when the record is not found. Something like this:

```
begin
  @user = User.find(id)
  respond_with @user
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  flash[:alert] = "User with id = #{id} not found"
  redirect_to users_path
end
```